# Soma (SUM) de uma coluna com formatação irregular

Tags: sql, sum, soma

Em minha tabela MySQL eu tenho uma coluna chamada "peso". Essa coluna tem os seguintes valores:

```
19.325
14.369
15.325
15.369
17.698
19.258
18.098
```

Preciso simplesmente realizar a soma, porém quando executo `select sum(peso) from tabela` ele me retorna o valor `119.44200000000001` ao invés de `119.442`.

Comment: Tente usar a função `ROUND` para arredondar os valores, por exemplo: `SELECT ROUND(SUM(peso), 3) AS peso FROM tabela;`

Comment: Valdeir, você foi rápido é certeiro. Perfeito, resolveu o meu problema. Muito Obrigado.

Comment: Se precisa de numeros exatos, a solução é usar tipos decimais exatos, e nada de pontos flutuantes. Round é uma solução para situações esporádicas e/ou pontuais.

Answer (score 1):

Cara, isto depende muito ,você usou float  ou double?
 Mas você pode no create usar o decimal, exemplo
  Create nome_tabela
(
// aqui eu estou passando duas casas apos a virgula

peso decimal(3, 2) not null,
);

Answer (score 0):

Tente fazer da seguinte forma...

SELECT FORMAT (SUM (peso), 'N', 'pt-br') 'Peso' FROM tabela